# Is it possible to create chat bot model passing intents , dialog from java using an API to AZURE bot service

Tags: java, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

1. below code is used to create intents and passing it to google.
2. I want to achieve the same using java + azure bot platform
3. I want to framework in which user will be able to pass intents to chat model present on azure.
4. that frame work will be created in java.
5. For now i am working on POC , in which i will pass intents as below code to azure.
6. i want to if its possible , is there any api same as google or amazon in azure as well.

```
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message.Text;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.IntentsClient;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.ProjectAgentName;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SankalpGCPChatBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> trainingPhrasesParts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> messageTexts = new ArrayList<>();

        trainingPhrasesParts.add("What is your name?");
        messageTexts.add("My name is Sankalp Bot.");
        String displayName = "SankalpTestIntent";
        String projectId = "newagent-257c8";

        try {
            createIntent(displayName, projectId, trainingPhrasesParts, messageTexts);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void authCompute() {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = ComputeEngineCredentials.create();
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
    }

    static void authImplicit() {
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
    }

    static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
    }

    public static Intent createIntent(
            String displayName,
            String projectId,
            List<String> trainingPhrasesParts,
            List<String> messageTexts) throws Exception {

        try (IntentsClient intentsClient = IntentsClient.create()) {
            ProjectAgentName parent = ProjectAgentName.of(projectId);

            List<Intent.TrainingPhrase> trainingPhrases = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String trainingPhrase : trainingPhrasesParts) {
                trainingPhrases.add(
                        Intent.TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addParts(
                                Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part.newBuilder().setText(trainingPhrase).build())
                                .build());
            }

            Message message = Message.newBuilder()
                    .setText(
                            Text.newBuilder()
                                    .addAllText(messageTexts).build()
                    ).build();

            Intent intent = Intent.newBuilder()
                    .setDisplayName(displayName)
                    .addMessages(message)
                    .addAllTrainingPhrases(trainingPhrases)
                    .build();

            Intent response = intentsClient.createIntent(parent, intent);
            System.out.format("Intent created: %s\n", response);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a google bot that connects to azure bot service, or are you asking if you can create a Microsoft Bot Framework bot using the java language /like/ a google bot. I"m a little confused.

Comment: I am asking can i create a micro soft bot , in which i want to create my intents, entities etc using java language

Comment: @user3675126 - Is JJ's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java version of the Microsoft Bot Framework is currently in preview (and is being actively worked on) as of this answer. You can track changes by monitoring the [Botbuilder-Java](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java) repo on Github.

The repo also includes a small number of samples, however none (AFAIK) have been built to show how to connect a Java bot to a Language understanding service such as LUIS. Also, bear in mind that as it is still in preview, some of the samples might not behave as expected.

Comment: can we use LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0 for above purpose . I wanted to create intents ,utterances etc  in luis application and we can create application using it.